# MySQL multiple remote sources queries

Tags: php, mysql

what's the best approach to achieve data moved between from 3 to 5 remote mysql sources + one local?

We are setting up "centralized" panel to control these (I know this isn't the best/secure way to do it), we don't have any kind of sensitive data anyway and work over https so this is the fastest way to achieve this.

Currently when we do insert / select to these, we are receiving huge load. Is it better to build API to each site to receive the select/update/insert per node (this might reduce/share the load between servers)? Or just keep connecting remotely to the mysql server and do all those directly to mysql?

Ofcourse we must build this api to fit each site and talk to other(s), this way each server would use just local mysql and receives all data thought api from other sources ?

There might be SELECT queries like 1000-2000 rows but these are rare, so this could be from 5 sources up to 8000 rows. Possibly there is a lot of grouping data and just making those values to stack i.e. plus each int values to get total from all sources.

Comment: Why would you want to retrieve 8000 rows at once its better to retrieve everything in smaller chuncks.... i guess your not gonna try and paste 8000 rows on 1 page??  because if you would i think most browsers are not that happy with that much data. and since a human will go over this data 100-200 rows at once will be more then enough per page. .... also could it be an option to have 1 slave server gathering from all these different sources? that will of course improve your performance alot for your "centralized" panel

Comment: You are right, we should make new tables and reports anyway, this might be the point where it really matters. Thought now we should make new one with only getting data that actually is shown. It could be possible aswell, but is there actually big difference in performance if using same server where we just push and pull data thought api OR directly to the remote mysql? I think our problem is those big queries where we collect data from multiple tables returning one big query wich is then multiplied with amount of the servers.

Comment: Maybe I should make this shorter, which one I should use? API at each mysql node to access remote mysql, or directly connect to remotemysqls from each where data is need ?:)

Comment: i would go for a API but still.... try not to go for HUGE result sets, limit the amount of returns and use pagination in your CMS dont try to dump 8000 rows in 1 page and you should not have to worrie alot about horrible performance

Comment: Ok, I will do that, that makes sense and our old table used json array to generate whole table and then make pagination so its time to update :) yet another thing came up, should I use first local to collect "main" data wich isn't changing i.e. stuff names, admin names etc, i.e. if collecting logs and then build up the result by looping each remote database thought api to collect data for the admin?? This sounds make sense to me because less data is returned.